# Normal map causing certain faces to get shaded

Tags: 3d, textures, 3dsmax, normal-mapping

I added a normal map to a MR arch & design material in Max 2012. I have a specular in the reflection color slot and a diffuse in the diffuse slot. As i increase the intensity of the normal map i certain faces get darker and they get really "obvious". Last time i was fiddling with this the exact same thing happened which made me quit normal maps and all. Some UV's are overlapping and the normal map is made with the Nvidia photoshop plugin. My scene just has a daylight system with a MR sun and MR sky.

Does anyone have an idea what is causing this?

[image]

As you can see the face gets shadowed as a whole. The face next to it has the same problem on the opposite corner you see the same effect but much less hard.

Comment: I haven't seen a lot of posts relating to 3dsmax or modeling applications on gamedev before. Maybe polycount would answer this faster?

Comment: No it is more a programming site, that is why most of my questions get closed because programmers don't have any idea how art works. However game development has many faces and gamedev SE should facilitate in every department. I asked already on gameartisans.org without results yet.

Comment: @MennoGouw I agree that most programmers don't know much about art but I doubt someone here will know the answer unless they used the program and faced that or similar issue. Plus I think sometimes questions get closed because they are not directly gamedev related. And thankfully you answered your own question while I was writing this comment.

Comment: Gamedev is a very broad topic. From design to finalizing the product. If a question about sound or graphics gets closed because programmers here deem it not related then this should be called gameprogramming instead of gamedev. Yeah @ConnorHollis comment was actually the indirect answer so i put it up here. Hopefully with more none programming question SE can attract some CG artists.

Answer (score 2):

The face normal has been flipped on the UV layout. Selecting the face with the issue and mirroring it should solve it.